# Site off-line with correct data in settings.php

Tags: 6, deployment, configuration

I'm trying to set up a development folder for a Drupal6 already existing website.

Under `htdocs/sites/<website>/settings.php` I have the following line in order to connect to the drupal6 DB:

```
$db_url = 'mysql://root:<mysql_password>@localhost/<drupal_db_name>';
```

If I try to enter mysql using the same login data, I can do it without any problems, so I know this data is correct.

But I still keep getting the "Site off-line" message.

I've also tried using settings.php in the "default" folder under `htdocs/sites/`, but it didn't solve the problem.

Any suggestions of what could I try in order to fix or debug this?

UPDATE: I have not taken the site down through admin. I've taken the folder from a production server (where it's working correctly), and I've placed it into another server. I've also made the same thing with the DB.

Comment: Have you taken the site down through admin ?

Comment: You said you placed it on another server. Did you also move your database? You're using @localhost, maybe you should use a different address? Also, what else does your site say besides site off-line? Something like "access denied"?

Comment: It says access denied, but I don't think I should change @localhost to something else, because the DB is in that same server.

Answer (score 2):

You probably haven't installed and/or enabled the PHP MySQL extension ([it's a requirement](http://drupal.org/requirements/php)). You can check by [creating a `phpinfo()` page](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/764/How+can+I+create+a+phpinfo.php+page?#gs) and searching for 'mysql'. If it's not there, you need to install and enable it. You don't say what server you're using, but if it's Ubuntu or a similar Debian-based variant, you can do this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

If you're on another platform, the steps will be a bit different, but you get the idea.